# How to Perform Pagination in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
        //this is my controller which gives me a list............
         @RequestMapping("/getList")
             public ModelAndView getList(Model model){
                 List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpList();  
                  Employee emp=new Employee();
                  model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
                  return new ModelAndView("empList", "empList", empList);  
             }
```

My question is i have a list of employees in one page.If i have 100 of employees i need show them in next page.So when i click on prev button the  prev list bust be displayed when i press on next next page must be displayed by keeping next and prev buttons.Will u please give me the solution of how to perform it.

Comment: Is there any way to do plz give me the solution

Comment: Use Spring Data JPA and create a repository. It supports Pagination (and Sorting!)

Comment: @RequestMapping("/getList")
  public ModelAndView getList(@RequestParam(value="page",required=false) Integer page,Model model,@RequestParam(value="page_size",required=false) Integer page_size){
   page=0;
   page_size=10;
   if(page==0){
    page=page+page_size;
   }
   List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpList1(page,page_size); 
    Employee emp=new Employee();
   
    model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
    return new ModelAndView("empList", "empList", empList);  
  }

Comment: this is my controller by this i need to perform i should not use jpa will u plz tell me hw to do?